# NED path error while running Veins/Omnet++ simulations on Ubuntu Server

Tags: simulation, omnet++, traffic-simulation, veins

I have setup a Linux server to run veins/omnet++ simulations on it. The main reason I am doing this is to decrease simulation time. The server is running Ubuntu Server 14.04.3, OMNET++ 4.6, SUMO 0.22.0 and VEINS 4a2. After installing OMNET and SUMO, I changed to VEINS root directory and run `./configure` and `make MODE=release -j 32`. This generated an executable `veins-4a2` file that I tried to run as:

```
./veins-4a2 -u Cmdenv -f examples/veins/omnetpp.ini //since omnetpp.ini is under examples folder
```

But I got the following error:

```
Loading NED files from /home/simulator/veins-4a2/examples/veins: 1
<!> Error: NED type `RSUExampleScenario' could not be fully resolved, due to a missing base type or interface.
```

Before running the previous command I did another ssh into machine to run the command `./sumo-launchd.py -vv -c sumo`.

My questions is what does the error refer to? And have I missed any steps during my installation/configuration? Am I doing the `make` step for veins properly?

Comment: Have you followed all steps from http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/ ? Is there a run script in your examples folder? Can you use this?

Comment: Hey. I deleted Veins and then re-did all the steps and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: [Specifying the NED Path](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec357), or have a look at `NED source folder` from project properties